# VMWare ESXi remote syslog format

Tags: vmware-vsphere, syslog, grafana

I've followed the [documentation](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2003322), host can connect to remote log port using `nc`, but no logs are received. As a remote syslog I'm using `Loki` and [Promtail](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/configuration/#syslog) which only supports `RFC 5424`.

Does ESXi ship this format? How the format can be changed?

Comment: Remote port you mean 514 udp/tcp where `promtail` is listening for incoming syslog events? I don't know what version of netcat ESXi uses but I would do: `echo 'sourcehost message text' | openbsd-nc -n -N -u -w 0 <promtail_ip> 514` and on host running `promtail` i would run wireshark to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not exactly what you wanted but you can always send to a syslog server like rsyslog and then forward from there.

The option `RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format` will ensure it's RFC5424:

```
action(type="omfwd" target="promtail-ip-adress" port="514" template="RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format" protocol="tcp")
```

Comment: where do i place that? in /etc/rsyslog.conf?